# How to find Listen and Open ports in Linux.?

Tags: linux, ports

I want to list Listen ports and Established ports and unused activated ports. I need to know commands for this..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32092493/1030675

Answer (score 2):

`netstat`is the command you need:

`-l` show listening sockets

`-p`show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

`-u` show UDP sockets

`t` show TCP sockets

Use `netstat -plutona`to show everything.